# Salesforce Data Event - Multi-Select Picklists - AMPScript in Email Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, multi-select

I need to be able to use a multi-select picklist field from Salesforce. This will always have 1 value as it comes from a webform. However for internally created records users need the ability to choose more than 1 option. When I use the Multi-Select picklist and 'test' my journey it throws an error containing :

> MULTICRITERIADECISION-1","Activity
>   Id":"8f7febe4-d944-48d8-95f4-fe29fd53e0e5","Activity
>   Type":"MULTICRITERIADECISION"}

I was hoping I could just place the field name from the Data Extension in the Email template. Do I need to handle the field in a particular way?

Comment: Interesting - have you heard from Salesforce support?

Comment: Indeed - It's on my list for today to raise as a question. I'll post any update here.

Comment: any news on this one LexR? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not much help but I couldn't get it  to work quickly enough so I changed the field that I was using. Not much help but the error didn't go away. To help I also recreated the AMPscript reference and a fresh data event data extension.